# How to divert the output of pig command to a text file in order to print it out?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

```
    2015-09-24 01:59:28,436 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]}
    2015-09-24 01:59:28,539 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
    2015-09-24 01:59:28,556 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
    2015-09-24 01:59:28,560 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
    2015-09-24 01:59:28,561 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
    2015-09-24 01:59:28,620 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
    2015-09-24 01:59:28,624 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
    2015-09-24 01:59:28,638 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
    2015-09-24 01:59:28,640 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
    2015-09-24 01:59:28,641 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - This job cannot be converted run in-process
    2015-09-24 01:59:29,268 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/vivek/Applications/pig/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-1176581946/tmp-2078805221/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar
    2015-09-24 01:59:29,452 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/vivek/Applications/pig/lib/automaton-1.11-8.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-1176581946/tmp-1750967439/automaton-1.11-8.jar
    2015-09-24 01:59:29,538 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/vivek/Applications/pig/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-1176581946/tmp1997290065/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
    2015-09-24 01:59:29,843 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/vivek/Applications/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-1176581946/tmp-256046780/guava-11.0.2.jar
    2015-09-24 01:59:29,990 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/vivek/Applications/pig/lib/joda-time-2.1.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-1176581946/tmp955728106/joda-time-2.1.jar
    2015-09-24 01:59:30,129 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
    2015-09-24 01:59:30,131 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
    2015-09-24 01:59:30,131 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cacche
    2015-09-24 01:59:30,132 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Setting key [pig.schematuple.classes] with classes to deserialize []
    2015-09-24 01:59:30,276 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
    2015-09-24 01:59:30,283 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
    2015-09-24 01:59:30,568 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
    2015-09-24 01:59:30,868 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
    2015-09-24 01:59:30,871 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
    2015-09-24 01:59:30,874 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 1
    2015-09-24 01:59:31,190 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - number of splits:1
    2015-09-24 01:59:31,499 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Submitting tokens for job: job_1443082231600_0003
    2015-09-24 01:59:31,516 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner - Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
    2015-09-24 01:59:31,704 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl - Submitted application application_1443082231600_0003
    2015-09-24 01:59:31,738 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job - The url to track the job: http://ubuntu:8088/proxy/application_1443082231600_0003/
    2015-09-24 01:59:31,742 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_1443082231600_0003
    2015-09-24 01:59:31,745 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases highsal,salaries
    2015-09-24 01:59:31,745 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: salaries[3,10],salaries[-1,-1],highsal[13,9] C:  R: 
    2015-09-24 01:59:31,781 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
    2015-09-24 01:59:31,782 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_1443082231600_0003]
2015-09-24 02:00:48,025 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 50% complete
2015-09-24 02:00:48,025 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_1443082231600_0003]
2015-09-24 02:00:53,055 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2015-09-24 02:00:53,104 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2015-09-24 02:00:58,180 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-09-24 02:00:59,182 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-09-24 02:01:00,185 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)        
(F,96,86000.0,95105)
(M,24,80000.0,95050)
(F,84,89000.0,94040)
(M,36,85000.0,95101)
(F,69,91000.0,95050)
(F,96,80000.0,95051)
(M,78,87000.0,95105)
(M,25,96000.0,95103)
(M,89,90000.0,95102)
(F,82,77000.0,95051)
(M,97,96000.0,95102)
(F,39,82000.0,95051)
(M,36,79000.0,95101)
(M,75,84000.0,95103)
(F,78,91000.0,95102)
(M,59,77000.0,95051)
(F,52,76000.0,95050)
(M,52,97000.0,95102)
(F,28,98000.0,95105)
(M,91,96000.0,94041)
(F,47,85000.0,95051)
(M,79,85000.0,95101)
(F,93,93000.0,95102)
(F,33,82000.0,95101)
(F,77,96000.0,95103)
(F,93,84000.0,95051)
(M,23,83000.0,95050)
(M,54,97000.0,95101)
(F,25,93000.0,94040)
(M,52,85000.0,95102)
(M,60,78000.0,94040)
(F,74,89000.0,94040)
(F,23,76000.0,95101)
(M,46,93000.0,95051)
(F,63,92000.0,95105)
(F,86,93000.0,95101)
(F,37,95000.0,95101)
(M,41,89000.0,95050)
(F,89,77000.0,94041)
(F,82,84000.0,95050)
(M,66,96000.0,95051)
(F,75,79000.0,95051)
(M,91,90000.0,95105)
(M,27,98000.0,95051)
(M,24,85000.0,94041)
(M,82,96000.0,95050)
(F,75,88000.0,95101)
(F,80,77000.0,95051)
(M,63,80000.0,95101)
(M,29,86000.0,95103)
(F,44,91000.0,95101)
(M,40,78000.0,95103)
(F,46,83000.0,95051)
(F,42,85000.0,95105)
(M,44,90000.0,95102)
(F,26,90000.0,94041)
(F,31,87000.0,95051)
(F,88,76000.0,95050)
(M,67,87000.0,95102)
(F,58,86000.0,94041)
(F,57,85000.0,95051)
(M,97,85000.0,95101)
(M,73,90000.0,95103)
(M,47,95000.0,95105)
(F,83,98000.0,94040)
(F,56,78000.0,95101)
(M,72,89000.0,94041)
(M,90,99000.0,95101)
(F,59,79000.0,95105)
(F,32,84000.0,95051)
(F,60,93000.0,95103)
(M,47,87000.0,94041)
(M,52,87000.0,95103)
(M,82,92000.0,95051)
(M,39,87000.0,95102)
(F,93,89000.0,95103)
(M,31,88000.0,95050)
(M,21,92000.0,94040)
(F,65,84000.0,95050)
(M,68,89000.0,94041)
(F,63,92000.0,94041)
(F,95,77000.0,95050)
(F,34,98000.0,95102)
(F,44,94000.0,94040)
(M,69,81000.0,95103)
(F,30,85000.0,95051)
(F,85,82000.0,95050)
(M,75,78000.0,94040)
(F,91,94000.0,95105)
(F,71,91000.0,94041)
(M,39,91000.0,95051)
(M,43,90000.0,95105)
(F,35,94000.0,94040)
(F,41,83000.0,95051)
(M,62,94000.0,94041)
(F,38,77000.0,94041)
(F,63,89000.0,95051)
(M,78,90000.0,95050)
(M,65,92000.0,95101)
(F,42,94000.0,95103)
(M,65,80000.0,95103)
(F,38,91000.0,95102)
(M,58,93000.0,94040)
(F,63,83000.0,95103)
(F,23,96000.0,95103)
(F,43,96000.0,95102)
(F,27,86000.0,94041)
(M,94,76000.0,94041)
(F,53,79000.0,94041)
(M,78,79000.0,95102)
(F,62,82000.0,95101)
(M,86,83000.0,95051)
(F,91,98000.0,95105)
(M,61,99000.0,95103)
(M,58,94000.0,95050)
(F,47,99000.0,95102)
(F,24,89000.0,95101)
(M,80,92000.0,95051)
(F,30,83000.0,95102)
(F,35,86000.0,95051)
(M,69,82000.0,95102)
(F,49,83000.0,95105)
(M,59,82000.0,95103)
(F,74,84000.0,95103)
(F,82,83000.0,95051)
(M,32,85000.0,95102)
(M,39,91000.0,95103)
(M,50,95000.0,95051)
(M,98,89000.0,95105)
(M,84,96000.0,95050)
(M,61,90000.0,95103)
(F,69,83000.0,95102)
(F,59,91000.0,95101)
(M,79,90000.0,95050)
(F,98,83000.0,95050)
(F,65,78000.0,94040)
(F,74,81000.0,95103)
(M,83,97000.0,95101)
(M,42,92000.0,95102)
(M,82,92000.0,95105)
(F,41,91000.0,94041)
(F,35,97000.0,94040)
(F,46,85000.0,95050)
(M,34,86000.0,94041)
(F,37,85000.0,94041)
(M,64,91000.0,94040)
(M,92,84000.0,95051)
(M,56,83000.0,95103)
(F,68,98000.0,95101)
(M,28,81000.0,95050)
(F,81,93000.0,95050)
(M,71,87000.0,95051)
(M,90,86000.0,95050)
(F,92,78000.0,94041)
(M,42,97000.0,95101)
(F,97,83000.0,94041)
(M,41,86000.0,95051)
(F,96,99000.0,95102)
(F,56,96000.0,95051)
(F,63,99000.0,95105)
(F,69,89000.0,95050)
(M,67,85000.0,95105)
(M,61,83000.0,95051)
(M,86,96000.0,95103)
(F,84,82000.0,94041)
(M,91,90000.0,95050)
(F,36,99000.0,94041)
(M,75,97000.0,95105)
(M,39,93000.0,95050)
(M,56,90000.0,95050)
(M,61,91000.0,95105)
(M,29,93000.0,94041)
(M,79,99000.0,95102)
(M,48,91000.0,95101)
(F,95,76000.0,95101)
(M,47,98000.0,95050)
(M,61,88000.0,95101)
(M,74,77000.0,95101)
(M,75,83000.0,94040)
(M,34,82000.0,95103)
(M,70,85000.0,95103)
(F,43,94000.0,94041)
(F,64,91000.0,95105)
(F,21,95000.0,95051)
(M,55,91000.0,95051)
(M,27,85000.0,95105)
(F,40,84000.0,94040)
(F,41,84000.0,94041)
(F,50,87000.0,95051)
(M,72,82000.0,95103)
(F,50,87000.0,95105)
(F,31,93000.0,95102)
(F,45,80000.0,95050)
(F,62,77000.0,94040)
(M,93,91000.0,95101)
(M,77,94000.0,95051)
(F,33,82000.0,95051)
(M,95,87000.0,95105)
(M,40,79000.0,95102)
(M,82,87000.0,95050)
(M,55,85000.0,95051)
(M,52,96000.0,95102)
(F,52,96000.0,95050)
(F,78,82000.0,95102)
(F,31,82000.0,94041)
(F,60,97000.0,95101)
(M,77,81000.0,95102)
(F,78,93000.0,95101)
(M,74,82000.0,94040)
(M,62,77000.0,95050)
(F,72,77000.0,95102)
(M,96,87000.0,94041)
(F,89,93000.0,95051)
(M,59,87000.0,95050)
(F,26,81000.0,95105)
(F,84,77000.0,95051)
(F,42,84000.0,94040)
(F,59,96000.0,94041)
(F,31,78000.0,95050)
(F,91,85000.0,95105)
(F,87,79000.0,95102)
(M,39,88000.0,95105)
(F,47,86000.0,95051)
(F,24,92000.0,95101)
(F,76,85000.0,95103)
(F,48,83000.0,95105)
(M,50,88000.0,95105)
(F,61,93000.0,94041)
(F,59,98000.0,95050)
(F,57,95000.0,95050)
(M,77,76000.0,95105)
(M,34,90000.0,95105)
(M,23,91000.0,95050)
(M,38,88000.0,95051)
(F,35,86000.0,95102)
(M,27,91000.0,95103)
(F,99,78000.0,95051)
(F,77,94000.0,94041)
(M,23,83000.0,95103)
(M,93,91000.0,95051)
(F,94,89000.0,95103)
(M,99,99000.0,95105)
(M,75,84000.0,94040)
(M,32,89000.0,94041)
(F,57,76000.0,94040)
(F,94,95000.0,95103)
(M,66,82000.0,94041)
(F,56,98000.0,94041)
(M,37,88000.0,95105)
(M,89,82000.0,95050)
(M,91,79000.0,95103)
(F,72,90000.0,95102)
(F,53,85000.0,95050)
(F,87,91000.0,95105)
(M,74,91000.0,95050)
(F,62,99000.0,95102)
(M,46,95000.0,95105)
(F,73,78000.0,95050)
(F,35,94000.0,95102)
(F,60,77000.0,95105)
(M,83,93000.0,95105)
(F,55,76000.0,95051)
(F,36,90000.0,95101)
(F,75,87000.0,95103)
(F,91,98000.0,95103)
(F,66,87000.0,95101)
(M,83,91000.0,95103)
(M,52,77000.0,94040)
(F,76,85000.0,95103)
(F,98,78000.0,95102)
(F,60,89000.0,95050)
(F,30,76000.0,95101)
(F,53,95000.0,95050)
(M,63,85000.0,95105)
(F,25,94000.0,95050)
(M,29,98000.0,95103)
(M,53,82000.0,95050)
(F,70,89000.0,95101)
(F,76,83000.0,95105)
(M,85,98000.0,95050)
(F,81,97000.0,95103)
(M,30,77000.0,94041)
(F,73,85000.0,95102)
(M,94,93000.0,95103)
(F,83,80000.0,95101)
(F,44,88000.0,94040)
(F,35,83000.0,95051)
(F,25,82000.0,94040)
(M,26,92000.0,95101)
(F,60,81000.0,95105)
(F,47,78000.0,94040)
(F,53,87000.0,94040)
(F,44,88000.0,95051)
(M,73,96000.0,95103)
(F,77,95000.0,95103)
(M,24,93000.0,95050)
(F,21,76000.0,95050)
(F,82,90000.0,95103)
(M,71,97000.0,95051)
(M,53,79000.0,95105)
(M,28,84000.0,94040)
(M,35,97000.0,95101)
(F,75,76000.0,94040)
(M,87,94000.0,94041)
(F,89,79000.0,95102)
(F,80,92000.0,95102)
(M,24,77000.0,95102)
(F,40,94000.0,95105)
(M,43,80000.0,94041)
(M,23,80000.0,94041)
(F,51,83000.0,94041)
(F,90,78000.0,94040)
(F,41,79000.0,95102)
(M,48,93000.0,94041)
(M,69,94000.0,94040)
(F,36,81000.0,95101)
(M,35,91000.0,95051)
(F,26,88000.0,95050)
(M,35,83000.0,94041)
(F,36,77000.0,95103)
(M,57,91000.0,95103)
(F,57,89000.0,95101)
(F,38,86000.0,94041)
(F,31,83000.0,95050)
(M,47,96000.0,94041)
(F,91,83000.0,95101)
(F,21,78000.0,95103)
(M,32,84000.0,95051)
(F,41,93000.0,94041)
(M,81,93000.0,95102)
(F,59,78000.0,95105)
(M,71,90000.0,95050)
(F,51,77000.0,95051)
(M,29,88000.0,95102)
(F,40,93000.0,95102)
(F,89,99000.0,95105)
(F,64,77000.0,95103)
(F,53,87000.0,94041)
(M,53,97000.0,94040)
(M,45,78000.0,94040)
(F,76,89000.0,94041)
(M,59,81000.0,95050)
(F,24,76000.0,94041)
(M,72,95000.0,95051)
(M,63,83000.0,94040)
(F,39,76000.0,94041)
(F,26,85000.0,95101)
(M,90,99000.0,95102)
(F,47,76000.0,95103)
(M,72,86000.0,95105)
(M,38,92000.0,95050)
(M,54,78000.0,95101)
(F,48,86000.0,95102)
(F,37,78000.0,94040)
(F,75,88000.0,95103)
(F,66,78000.0,95050)
(M,58,80000.0,94040)
(M,84,88000.0,95050)
(F,35,94000.0,95050)
(M,57,88000.0,95102)
(M,68,83000.0,95050)
(M,37,91000.0,95103)
(M,65,79000.0,95101)
(M,65,85000.0,95101)
(F,97,83000.0,95102)
(M,43,83000.0,95051)
(F,73,82000.0,95103)
(M,89,87000.0,95050)
(F,74,84000.0,95103)
(M,73,90000.0,94041)
(F,46,97000.0,95103)
(M,36,82000.0,94041)
(M,80,82000.0,95105)
(F,78,79000.0,95102)
(M,67,96000.0,94040)
(F,48,98000.0,95102)
(F,82,86000.0,95050)
(M,79,80000.0,95050)
(M,96,84000.0,95103)
(M,51,87000.0,94040)
(F,29,84000.0,95051)
(M,47,86000.0,94040)
(M,54,96000.0,94041)
(F,80,94000.0,94041)
(F,92,93000.0,95103)
(F,59,79000.0,95050)
(M,95,80000.0,95050)
(M,67,92000.0,94040)
(F,23,98000.0,95103)
(M,91,82000.0,95051)
(M,27,89000.0,95105)
(M,43,77000.0,94041)
(F,65,83000.0,94040)
(F,65,82000.0,95051)
(M,43,98000.0,95105)
(F,51,86000.0,95102)
(M,76,83000.0,95051)
(F,25,92000.0,94040)
(M,48,76000.0,95102)
(F,43,86000.0,95050)
(F,57,83000.0,95101)
(F,48,84000.0,95051)
(M,37,98000.0,95102)
(F,98,81000.0,95105)
(M,78,86000.0,94041)
(F,34,93000.0,95102)
(M,53,94000.0,95102)
(M,69,98000.0,94040)
(F,70,84000.0,94041)
(F,89,87000.0,94040)
(F,52,89000.0,95102)
(F,84,79000.0,95102)
(M,44,86000.0,94041)
(M,51,93000.0,94041)
(M,98,81000.0,95102)
(F,82,77000.0,95101)
(M,50,82000.0,95103)
(F,59,76000.0,95051)
(M,29,76000.0,94041)
(F,30,81000.0,95051)
(F,22,96000.0,95105)
(M,64,88000.0,94040)
(M,80,78000.0,95102)
(F,94,85000.0,95051)
(M,63,95000.0,95103)
(F,51,78000.0,95050)
(M,39,94000.0,95105)
(M,80,85000.0,95101)
(M,92,89000.0,95102)
(M,44,88000.0,95103)
(M,57,92000.0,95050)
(F,64,94000.0,95051)
(F,88,91000.0,95102)
(F,43,83000.0,95101)
(F,33,93000.0,95050)
(M,64,92000.0,95102)
(M,91,92000.0,95050)
(F,32,88000.0,95105)
(M,78,87000.0,94041)
(F,64,85000.0,94040)
(M,93,96000.0,95102)
(F,72,98000.0,95103)
(M,68,76000.0,95051)
(M,52,95000.0,95050)
(F,75,93000.0,95103)
(M,45,85000.0,94041)
(F,70,98000.0,95051)
(F,74,96000.0,95101)
(F,81,85000.0,95102)
(M,83,91000.0,95105)
(M,32,89000.0,95101)
(F,58,90000.0,94041)
(M,55,80000.0,95050)
(F,23,79000.0,95051)
(M,91,79000.0,95103)
(F,21,98000.0,95102)
(F,57,91000.0,95101)
(M,58,91000.0,95051)
(F,41,94000.0,95101)
(M,67,95000.0,94041)
(M,69,80000.0,95101)
(M,23,77000.0,94041)
(F,94,92000.0,95105)
(F,60,92000.0,95051)
(F,53,84000.0,94041)
(F,48,98000.0,95103)
(M,70,88000.0,95051)
(M,76,94000.0,95103)
(F,22,88000.0,94040)
(F,80,81000.0,95102)
(F,57,80000.0,95051)
(F,57,99000.0,95103)
(M,50,78000.0,95050)
(M,40,81000.0,95050)
(F,93,97000.0,95050)
(M,40,80000.0,94041)
(M,35,91000.0,95101)
(F,50,96000.0,94041)
(F,27,90000.0,95105)
(F,23,91000.0,95105)
(M,49,80000.0,94041)
(M,90,98000.0,95105)
(M,29,91000.0,95050)
(F,99,83000.0,95103)
(F,43,83000.0,94040)
(F,30,90000.0,94041)
(F,96,97000.0,95102)
(M,83,77000.0,95103)
(F,77,97000.0,94040)
(F,74,98000.0,95105)
(F,96,96000.0,95103)
(F,37,81000.0,94041)
(M,82,91000.0,94040)
(F,33,90000.0,95101)
(F,35,86000.0,95102)
(F,67,87000.0,95105)
(M,95,95000.0,95051)
(M,82,95000.0,95101)
(F,26,76000.0,95050)
(F,65,84000.0,95103)
(F,34,91000.0,95102)
(F,48,81000.0,94040)
(F,93,84000.0,94041)
(F,37,79000.0,95105)
(M,77,84000.0,95102)
(M,94,78000.0,94040)
(M,28,79000.0,95051)
(F,30,80000.0,94041)
(F,54,80000.0,95103)
(F,93,96000.0,95105)
(F,45,78000.0,94041)
```

---

right now i'm just executing pig command .I wanna direct or make a copy of output at execution time
let it is really difficult to take a snapshot of it.
just suggest a solution to overcome from it.

the code ILLUSTRATE THE OUTPUT OF THE COMMAND

```
grunt>salaries= load 'salaries' using PigStorage(',') As (gender, age,salary,zip);
grunt> salaries= load 'salaries' using PigStorage(',') As (gender:chararray,age:int,salary:double,zip:long);
grunt>highsal= filter salaries by salary > 75000;
grunt>dump highsal;
```

WHEN THE ABOVE COMMAND EXECUTED THE OUTPUT LISTING ABOVE WIILL BE DISPLAYED .
JUST I HAVE COPIED salaries.txt from local FS to hdfs
.

```
grunt> store highsal into 'file';
2015-09-24 02:59:15,981 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse: 
<line 1, column 6> Undefined alias: highsal
Details at logfile: /home/vivek/pig_1443088724224.log
grunt>
```

i'm still getting error by suggested query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined "highsal" alias when trying to run STORE command. 
Pig do not store any alias previous session. you have to execute all your command in one session or write a pig script and invoke it.

Try like :

```
grunt>salaries= load 'salaries' using PigStorage(',') As (gender, age,salary,zip);
grunt> salaries= load 'salaries' using PigStorage(',') As (gender:chararray,age:int,salary:double,zip:long);
grunt>highsal= filter salaries by salary > 75000;
grunt>STORE highsal INTO 'file';
```

This will store the "highsal" content in a file name 'file/part-x-xxxxx' on user's HDFS directory. You can also provide HDFS absolute directory path instead of `'file'` if you want to wish to store data in directory other than users home directory

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
store highsal into 'file';
```

Have a look at [apache pig](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/) documentation for all commands.